# Fallback Mode on Intel HD 4000 on Ubuntu 12.04.1?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

Just built a system w/ a ivy bridge CPU (Xeon E3-1245 v2) with Intel HD 4000 onboard graphics, board is an Asrock H77 ProM.

I had loaded Ubuntu server 12.04.1 onto it, but wanted to fool around w/ gnome 3.

I installed gnome-shell, which didn't work, then gnome, which did, but only loads on fallback mode - the video is recognized as  **"VESA: sandy/ivy bridge graphics"**

I tried installing the whole ubuntu-desktop shebang but it's still in fallback graphics.

Any way to get the full eye candy?

Comment: What do you mean by "then gnome"? What packages did you install exactly? As for Unity, you have to select Ubuntu at the login screen, otherwise, it will always load Gnome Classic, aka fallback.

Comment: did you try `startx`?

Answer (score 1):

to install gnome3 on ubuntu 12.04 :

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

Now be sure to reboot your computer and when you are prompted with your login screen you have additional options (click on the little Ubuntu icon next to your login name)

install gnome tweak tool:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

**According to what you've mentioned the VESA is the right driver for intel graphics

Comment: Ok - I just did the standard 'gnome' package or metapackage - is this not the latest gnome 3 environment?